# Android embedded apks

Tags: android, installation, dex

I have two applications (apk files) in android. Let's say app1.apk and app2.apk. I am wondering if it is possible from app1.apk to start any activity at app2.apk without installing the app2.apk. The problem is that I want to hide app2.apk from the user. Is it possible?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: run an apk that is not installed? that's an interesting prospect... What you can do is package your 2 apps in one apk

Answer (score 4):

You cant run an app that isnt installed.. It hasnt gone through any of the security steps.

Aka, the user hasnt granted it permission to run (done during install). So it will never be possible.

Why dont you bundle your activities that are in app2, into app1. Then they will be installed with app1, and runnable.

Comment: I am not the developer of both applications. The apk is auto generated from an application that I have installed in my PC. I imagine it, like using one apk like a jar library just how it happens at Java. Import a jar or zip file (apk in our occasion) into the project and call the included classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do as everyone else has mentioned, put all your activities into one bundled app, you can use Intents to start and even get results from other activities.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) may be of help, which comes from the developer guide for Android.